# How to use Pascal code in R-project?

Tags: r, io, pascal

I am using R-project to deal with my statistics, but due to the amount of resources needed, R is struggling while pascal would do it way faster. Is there a way to use pascal code in R-project?

Comment: I can't say I have any idea why you would want to do what you are asking (Pascal!!!???, Really???!!!). On the other hand I am really interested to hear the answer.

Comment: You can use `system` to call external programs (written in any language you fancy) from R. A simple workflow would be: R writes a CSV file, launches an external program, the external program reads the CSV file, does something with it, writes another CSV file, R reads the new CSV file, etc.

Comment: Maybe you could provide some more detail as to what you do. Maybe we can help you solve your problem much more quickly in R. Especially when programming Pascal-like in R, you could be doing things very inefficiently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can compile it to a dll (windows) or a .so (unix) file then you might be able to use the same mechanism as used for C and Fortran. You load the dll/.so with the dyn.load() function and then call it with .C("functionname").

However, this is all very dependent on your operating system, your compiler, and your code.

R helps Fortran and C programmers by providing the SHLIB command. One just does:

```
R CMD SHLIB foo.f
```

and gets a foo.so back. Then do dyn.load("foo.so") and you can call the Fortran code with .C("subname",as.integer(1),as.double(pi)) and so on.

Perhaps if you can convert your pascal to C (is there a 'p2c' converter?).

Comment: It's quite easy to compile to a DLL with the FreePascal compiler. Make sure that the exports are marked with `cdecl` to get the right calling convention. As for `p2c` I would not trust it, it's not in the same class as the quite wonderful `f2c`.

Comment: What about the GNU Pascal compiler? I wonder how much of a Makefile you'd need to get R CMD SHLIB working with .pas files?

Comment: GNU Pascal could fly also. I'm just more familiar with FPC which is more actively developed. That said, something dating from the ark might be appropriate here!  ;-)

Comment: I last used Pascal on the ZX Spectrum in 1983.

Comment: I on the other hand, write in Pascal every day of my life!

Answer (score 1):

Is it this you need (or the other way round?)

https://github.com/swissr/rpascal